# I need for my android bluetooth control application

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, bluetooth

I need some help my license finishing project.
I write this code and there is no syntax eror but application stopped. 
this code and xml file added below.I want to only scan nearby bluetooth device and display this device on the listview

MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
private BluetoothAdapter btadapter;
private ArrayAdapter<String>arrayAdapter;
private ArrayList<String> devicelist;
private ListView list;
private static final int BT_REQUEST_ENABLE =1;
private static final int BT_VISIABLE_ENABLE = 12 ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final CheckBox visibilitycontol = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.visibilitycontrol);
     ListView list             = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    btadapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

    // Bluetooth device control
    if ( btadapter == null)
    {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bluetooth Device Not Available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}

    // Bluetooth status check
    if ( !btadapter.isEnabled() )
    {   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please Turn On The Bluetooth Device",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent bt_request_intent = new Intent((BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE));
        startActivityForResult(bt_request_intent , BT_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    }
    else
    {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bluetooth Device Already Turned On",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}


    // Bluetooth visibility control
    visibilitycontol.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            if ( visibilitycontol.isChecked() )
            {
                Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
                discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 120);
                startActivityForResult(discoverableIntent , BT_VISIABLE_ENABLE);}
        }
    });
}

// discovering new device
public final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"DEVICE FOUND",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

            String devicename = device.getName();
            String deviceadress = device.getAddress();

            ArrayList<String> devicelist = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>btdevicelist = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();

            btdevicelist.add(device);
            devicelist.add(devicename+"\n"+deviceadress);

            list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            list.refreshDrawableState();


        }

    }
};

// Scan button code
public void scan(View view)
{
    if(btadapter.isDiscovering()) {btadapter.cancelDiscovery();}
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Searching for devices...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,devicelist);
    btadapter.startDiscovery();

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if( requestCode == BT_REQUEST_ENABLE )
    {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth Device Is Turning On", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if ( resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
        {finish();}

    }

    if( requestCode == BT_VISIABLE_ENABLE)
    {
        if (resultCode == 120)
        {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Now Device Visiable For a 120 seconds!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}

        else {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Give The Visibility Permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }
    }

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{super.onDestroy(); unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);}
```

}

and my XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.fatih.bluetoothcontrol.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:text="Bluetooth Control Application"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView2" />

<CheckBox
    android:text="Make This Device Visiable"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/visibilitycontrol"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp" />

<TextView
    android:text="00:00"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/counter"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginStart="260dp" />

<TextView
    android:text="Remaining Time for Visibility"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginEnd="21dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/visibilitycontrol"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView2" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_dropdown_light_frame"
    android:id="@+id/listView" />

<Button
    android:text="Control Menu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/controlmenu"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="300dp" />

<Button
    android:text="scan"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/counter"
    android:id="@+id/scan"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:onClick="scan" />


<Button
    android:text=" connect"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/connect"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scan"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
     />
```

error :

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.fatih.bluetoothcontrol, PID: 16078
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.bluetooth.device.action.FOUND flg=0x10 (has extras) } in com.example.fatih.bluetoothcontrol.MainActivity$2@32531784
                  at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:933)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.fatih.bluetoothcontrol.MainActivity$2.onReceive(MainActivity.java:97)
                  at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:923)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException` That is never good!

Comment: In future questions try to write a clear subject, it will help another users having the same issue.

Comment: as I mentioned before I wish only scan nearby bluetooth device and display this device on the listview and I can try this code at least one bluetooth device open and visiable I am sure this  the main point : listAdapter why null or new discoverd devices why to import a array list   I am looking for this question answer